# Azure, edit in visual studio online option - gone missing

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have two azurewebsites, in the azure management portal looking at the 'dashboard' both sites had a  'edit in visual online PREVIEW' option. This option has now disappeared on one of the sites - any possible reasons?. I have tried logout, close browser, clear cache etc..

Answer (score 0):

Have you already opened it in Visual Studio?  If so, just open Visual Studio and the solution will be listed under the Recent section of the start page.  If it's not there, click the Recent Projects and Solutions option in the FILE menu.  As for why it disappeared, hard to say. I just started using Visual Studio Online (aka TFS) and have found that while very convenient and easy... things are a little weird sometimes.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I'm on a mac so not the desktop VS but the browser based one that runs directly from an azure website, 'Monaco' is the codename.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! - The switch to enable it on the config pane was off. - Thanks